# JIRA: How to assign Feature as a subtask to EPIC

Tags: jira

Is it possible to assign feature as a subtask of epic in JIRA?

We are used to creating development tasks as a features and QA as a subtasks for those features. But now we are trying to use epic for new internal project and I don't know how to add features under the epic.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to add a sub-task in your epic.
The epic is used as a "link", you can specify which epic your features(jiras) belongs to in issue edit screen. The features themselves does not need to be a sub-task of the epic.
QA will still be able to create sub-task off your features.
Here are documentation from Atlassian
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Working+with+Epics